# Resources to learn IIS on Windows Server 2012

Tags: server, webserver, iis

I'm trying to learn how to manage IIS on Windows Server 2012 but I'm not sure where to look at. Can someone point out some books, videos, tutorials or other resources about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great place to start learning about IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 is at `IIS.net`:

[Get Started with IIS, a web server built with you in mind...](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis)

Each section (1-8) contains comprehensive, but relatively easy to understand articles.

For video tutorials on IIS 8, this [YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWY93AcExoRWEcaxG-soaUwNKYH2FhMZf) has a fairly complete series (though you might have to pause/rewind them to understand the presenter).

For even more comprehensive coverage, obtain a copy of [Professional Microsoft IIS 8](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Microsoft-IIS-8.productCd-1118439406.html) at Wrox.

Of course the best way to learn about IIS 8 is to start using it so you can pinpoint what you want to serve and do with it, and then read up on those topics versus getting buried in all the fine details :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for the resources @Dan, I'm sure this will help a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure you won't find it as daunting as it may seem at first, and you'll be an expert in no time :-)